# Importing file as list. \n after every item

Tags: file, list, python-3.x

Sorry in advance if this has already been answered some where else in this forum, but I do not have much time to search.

I have stored a number of lists in different files, and this is what one such file contains:

---

13

13

10

---

This works fine, however, when I import the file as a list into another program:

```
players = open("DATA/Players.txt").readlines()
skills = open("DATA/Skills.txt").readlines()
strengths = open("DATA/Strengths.txt").readlines()
```

It has the (\n)/(newline) after every item as you can see below.

```
['13\n', '13\n', '10\n']
```

How can I get rid of this when I import the list? I'm sure there must be a simple solution.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `strip`:

```
>>> a = 'b\n'
>>> a.strip()
'b'
```

Or more appropriately `rstrip()`, if your `\n` only appears to the right of the string:

```
>>> a.rstrip()
'b'
```

In a list:

```
>>> l = ['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n']
>>> no_ns = [var.rstrip() for var in l]
>>> no_ns
['a', 'b', 'c']
```